# How can I use NotificationListenerService to collect and display/delete notifications?

Tags: java, android, notifications

I've been trying to learn how to use notifications in Android by creating an application that creates, displays, and deletes notifications with button clicks (to clarify it will display the notifications in app). Now I can easily get my program to create notifications but when I try to delete the notification or display it I keep getting nulls and when I change the code up nothing. I found a few tutorials that helped me understand what I should be doing but the code they wrote did not work and I've hit a wall at this point. Here is my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView txtView;
private NotificationReceiver nReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    nReceiver = new NotificationReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.testing.notify.NOTIFICATION");
    registerReceiver(nReceiver,filter);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(nReceiver);
}

public void buttonClicked(View v){

    if(v.getId() == R.id.btnCreateNotify){
        NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder ncomp = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        ncomp.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        ncomp.setContentTitle("Notify");
        ncomp.setContentText("Notification Listener Service Example");
        ncomp.setTicker("Notification Listener Service Example");
        ncomp.setAutoCancel(true);
        nManager.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(),ncomp.build());
    }
    else if(v.getId() == R.id.btnClearNotify){
        Intent i = new Intent("com.testing.notify.NOTIFICATION");
        i.putExtra("command","clearall");
        sendBroadcast(i);
    }
    else if(v.getId() == R.id.btnListNotify){
        Intent i = new Intent("com.testing.notify.NOTIFICATION");
        i.putExtra("command","list");
        sendBroadcast(i);
    }

}

class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String temp = intent.getStringExtra("notification_event") + "n" + txtView.getText();
        txtView.setText(temp);
    }
}
```

And here is the code to my notification service class

```
public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {

private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
private NLServiceReceiver nlservicereceiver;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    nlservicereceiver = new NLServiceReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.testing.notify.NOTIFICATION");
    registerReceiver(nlservicereceiver,filter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(nlservicereceiver);
}

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

    Log.i(TAG,"**********  onNotificationPosted");
    Log.i(TAG,"ID :" + sbn.getId() + "t" + sbn.getNotification().tickerText + "t" + sbn.getPackageName());
    Intent i = new  Intent("com.testing.notify.NOTIFICATION");
    i.putExtra("notification_event","onNotificationPosted :" + sbn.getPackageName() + "n");
    sendBroadcast(i);

}

@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    Log.i(TAG,"********** onNotificationRemoved");
    Log.i(TAG,"ID :" + sbn.getId() + "t" + sbn.getNotification().tickerText +"t" + sbn.getPackageName());
    Intent i = new  Intent("com.testing.notify.NOTIFICATION");
    i.putExtra("notification_event","onNotificationRemoved :" + sbn.getPackageName() + "n");

    sendBroadcast(i);
}

class NLServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getStringExtra("command").equals("clearall")){
            NotificationManager notifManager= (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notifManager.cancelAll();
        }
        else if(intent.getStringExtra("command").equals("list")){
            Intent i1 = new  Intent("com.testing.notify.NOTIFICATION");
            i1.putExtra("notification_event","=====================");
            sendBroadcast(i1);
            int i=1;
            for (StatusBarNotification sbn : NotificationService.this.getActiveNotifications()) {
                Intent i2 = new  Intent("com.testing.notify.NOTIFICATION");
                i2.putExtra("notification_event",i +" " + sbn.getPackageName() + "n");
                sendBroadcast(i2);
                i++;
            }
            Intent i3 = new  Intent("com.testing.notify.NOTIFICATION");
            i3.putExtra("notification_event","===== Notification List ====");
            sendBroadcast(i3);

        }

    }
}
```

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. What exactly are the problems you are experiencing? It's not enough to say "I keep getting nulls".

Comment: When I click on the button that is supposed to display my notifications instead of the notifications "null" is printed. Same for when I click to delete all notifications.

Comment: Are you intentionally using the same intent action for both of your dynamically registered receivers? That seems confusing--broadcasts intended for one will go to both.

Comment: I had multiple set up but it wasn't working and after searching for a while online I found one that was supposed to work that grouped them together. It didn't work obviously but I did not switch the code back.